# php loop inside accordion not displaying correctly

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, accordion

In my database i have a table called *publi* inside this table i have two columns *pub_year* and *pub_publi*

Example of the table *publi* content :

```html
<table  border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>content_2016_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>content_2016_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>content_2016_3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>content_2015_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>content_2015_2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and i want this output

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2016">2016</button>
  <div id="2016" class="collapse">
    content_2016_1 <br>
    content_2016_2 <br>
    content_2016_3 <br>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2015">2015</button>
  <div id="2015" class="collapse">
    content_2015_1 <br>
    content_2015_2 <br>
  </div>
```

and this is my code :

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM publi where pub_type=0 order by pub_year DESC, pub_publi ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$previous =0;
while ($val = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    if ($previous <> $val['pub_year'])
    {
        $previous = $val['pub_year'];
        $year = $previous;

        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#';
        echo $year;
        echo '">';
        echo $year;
        echo '</button>';
        echo '<div id="';
        echo $year;
        echo '" class="collapse">';

        $Temp = highlight("person1",$val['pub_publi'],"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person2",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person3",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person4",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person5",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person6",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person7",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person8",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person9",$Temp,"0000FF");
        $Temp = highlight("person10",$Temp,"0000FF");


        echo '<a target=blank href="http://www.test.com/query.f?term=' . $val['pub_pubmed'] . '";)><img border="0" src="img/test.gif" align=MIDDLE alt="Search in  for ' . $val['pub_publi'] . '"></a>';
        echo $Temp;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

but the result that i get is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2016">2016</button>
<div id="2016" class="collapse">
    content_2016_1 <br>
</div>

content_2016_2


content_2016_3

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2015">2015</button>
<div id="2015" class="collapse">
content_2015_1 <br>

</div>
content_2015_2 <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are grouping the data by pub_year is correct but from your example, you are only outputting information when group is changing.

I would propose something similar:

```
    <?php
        $previous = false;
        while ($val = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            // when group is changing, end previous and start new
            if ($previous <> $val['pub_year']) {

                // end previous group html markup
                if ($previous !== false) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                $previous = $val['pub_year'];
                $year = $previous;

                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#' . $year . '>' . $year . '</button>';
                echo '<div id="' . $year . '" class="collapse">';
            }

            // always output data inside group
            $Temp = highlight("person1",$val['pub_publi'],"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person2",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person3",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person4",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person5",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person6",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person7",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person8",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person9",$Temp,"0000FF");
            $Temp = highlight("person10",$Temp,"0000FF");

            echo $Temp . '<br>';
        }

        // end last group html markup
        if ($previous !== false) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
?>
```